# custom number field input on yaml forms

Tags: 8, forms

I need to ask the user for an 8-digit number within a yaml form.

the number I need is 12345678 and goes is this layout: 1.234.567-8

is it possible to ask the user for this 8-digit number field and display it as 1.234.567-8 ?

ideally the field would be rendered to the user as: _ . _ _ _ . _ _ _ - _ while it's being filled.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The YAML Form module supports [inputmasks](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) which can be configured to handle any desired input format. The submitted value will match your input mask. If you need to submitted value to be converted to a number, you will have to write an update hook to do the conversion.